# Excercise about convex functions counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm self-studying real analysis using A course in mathematical analysis by Garling

One of the problems after the subsection on convex functions defines a function as midpoint convex if
$$f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \leq \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$$
The problem is then to prove that, if f is midpoint convex, $h\gt 0$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$
$$\frac{f(c-h)-f(c)}{n+1} \leq f(c+\frac{h}{n}) - f(c)$$
I don't think this statement is true. Let $f(x) = x^2,$ $n = 1,$ $ c = -1$ and $h = 0.25$

f(x) is midpoint convex as $$\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4} \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$ is equivalent to
$$2ab \leq a^2+b^2$$ which is true but $$\frac{f(-1.25)-f(-1)}{2} = 0.28125 \gt -0.4375 = f(-0.75) - f(1)$$

Comment: Another counterexample: Take a decreasing straight line.LHS is +ve, RHS is negative.